# How to improve efficiency of my redirect code

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have this include at the top of all of my ASP pages, to redirect to https for all pages NOT in folders called "words" and "generators". I don't want them on ssl as I heard moving to SSL can have a big impact on AdSense income.

I also redirect so that if a user ends up on an SSL version of pages in the words and generators folders, it takes them to the non ssl page.

And finally I have one that redirects from the www version of a page to the non www version, e.g. www.test.co.uk to test.co.uk

My code is below.

I wondered if I am doing this in a very resource intensive way and if there is a better way to do it using web config or something like that, or is it a case of if it isn't broken, don't fix it?

I realise my code is very basic and clunky, sorry.

```
SERVER_NAME =  lcase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"))
SCRIPT_NAME =  lcase(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
QUERY_STRING = lcase(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"))
SECURE_MODE =  lcase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT_SECURE"))

str0 = request.servervariables("url")
arrFolderData = Split(str0, "/")
strLastFolder = arrFolderData(UBound(arrFolderData)-1)
words_str = instr(strLastFolder,"words")
gens_str = instr(strLastFolder,"generators")

'' if page = http, and page is not in "words" or "generators" folder then redirect to https version of page

if SECURE_MODE = 0 AND words_str = 0 AND gens_str = 0 then

    SERVER_NAME = replace(SERVER_NAME, "www.", "")

    go_to_url = ""
    go_to_url = go_to_url & "https://"
    go_to_url = go_to_url & SERVER_NAME
    go_to_url = go_to_url & SCRIPT_NAME

    if QUERY_STRING <> "" then
        go_to_url = go_to_url & "?" & QUERY_STRING
    end if

    Response.Buffer = true
    Response.Status = "301 Redirect"
    Response.AddHeader "Location", lcase(go_to_url)
    Response.End

end if

'' if page = https, and page is in "words" or "generators" folder then redirect to http version of page

if SECURE_MODE = 1 AND (words_str = 1 OR gens_str = 1) then

    SERVER_NAME = replace(SERVER_NAME, "www.", "")

    go_to_url = ""
    go_to_url = go_to_url & "http://"
    go_to_url = go_to_url & SERVER_NAME
    go_to_url = go_to_url & SCRIPT_NAME

    if QUERY_STRING <> "" then
        go_to_url = go_to_url & "?" & QUERY_STRING
    end if

    Response.Buffer = true
    Response.Status = "301 Redirect"
    Response.AddHeader "Location", lcase(go_to_url)
    Response.End

end if


'' redirect to non "www" version of page
if left(SERVER_NAME,3) = "www" then

    SERVER_NAME = replace(SERVER_NAME, "www.", "")

    go_to_url = ""
    go_to_url = go_to_url & "http://"
    go_to_url = go_to_url & SERVER_NAME
    go_to_url = go_to_url & SCRIPT_NAME

    if QUERY_STRING <> "" then
        go_to_url = go_to_url & "?" & QUERY_STRING
    end if

    Response.Buffer = true
    Response.Status = "301 Redirect"
    Response.AddHeader "Location", lcase(go_to_url)
    Response.End

end if
```

---

Thanks to the help from @Carlos Aguilar Mares I was able to replace the code above with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Canonical HostName"  stopProcessing="true">
                    <!-- Redirect to the non-www host -->
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)$"  />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="NON HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <!-- Redirect to HTTPS as long as pages are not in words, generators or v folders -->
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/words/[a-z 0-9]*" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/generators/[a-z 0-9]*" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/v/[a-z 0-9]*" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that could be easily done and likely much faster (no longer in script, no longer parsing the code, regex and logic in native code, plus more maintainable, etc) if using URL Rewrite and configuring that in your web.config.

The rules would look something like the following:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="NON HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <!-- Redirect to HTTPS as long as it does not end in words/generators -->
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(words|generators)$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <!-- Redirect to HTTPS as long as it ends in words/generators -->
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(words|generators)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Canonical HostName"  stopProcessing="true">
                    <!-- Redirect to the non-www host -->
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)$"  />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks @Carlos Aguilar Mares!